# Is there and api to get details of Alexa skill from Amazon Alexa Skill Store

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-product-api

I want to programmatically fetch the details of my alexa skill listed on amazon alexa store to share it on social platforms.
Is there an api to fetch the details, provided skill name, skill id, author, etc.

I read about AWS Product Advertising API, but I am not sure it will get the skill details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/smapi-overview.html. Or you may elect to just use a CLI command to pull specific skill info - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#get-skill-subcommand.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not I am looking for. 
I think I have put the question in wrong way, let me rephrase it,
**Is there a way to get skill url listed on alexa store using skillId programmatically?**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://github.com/dale3h/alexa-skills-list this repository contain a js which helps you to generate a list of skills available in Alexa.

Note: The repository is not updated quite a while, used this repository to get a list of skill 5-6 months back. I am not entirely sure this method still works.